# How to read user's input from bash (when catting a script)

Tags: bash

I have a long bash script that essentially installs a bunch of prerequisites for a user; however, I'm trying to figure out why I can't catch their input when they run `cat https://www.my-site.org | bash` but if it's run like `./script.sh` then it works fine.

For example, here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " [*] Please do not cancel this script as it is running in the background."
echo " [*] You will receive a message here once the script has completed installing its prerequisites."
read -p " [*] Press enter to acknowledge and continue..."
```

The `read` command works fine if I run the script with `./script.sh` but it doesn't work fine if I `cat script.sh | bash`.

Are there any arguments in bash that I should be using in addition to the way I'm using it for this to work properly?

Tried with `--` and still no luck:

```
root@ip-10-20-46-59:~# cat getting_started.sh | bash --
 [*] Please do not cancel this script as it is running in the background.
 [*] You will receive a message here once the script has completed installing its prerequisites.
root@ip-10-20-46-59:~#
```

Comment: I am not sure on this, but sometimes you need to provide 2 dashes. `cat https://www.my-site.org | bash --`

Comment: Tried this as well, but still no luck, it just continued as if it didn't exist. Updated OP to contain results.

Comment: Cross site dupe: [Possible to get a bash script to accept input from terminal if its stdin has been redirected?](https://superuser.com/q/834502/372008)

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW. this solves this.

Comment: We have it answered here on Stack Overflow as well. Give me a few minutes and I'll find the existing instance.

Comment: BTW, in general, `cat anything | somecommand` is better replaced with `<anything somecommand` or `somecommand <anything`. Not an _enormous_ difference when what you're reading the data from is bash, but for other commands (`tail`, `wc -c`, and others) it can mean the difference between constant-time operation and O(n) operation that scales with length; or with `sort`, it can mean the difference between needing to work front-to-back vs being able to split into threads that sort different subsets of the file in parallel and then do a cheaper merge sort between their results.